# Multiply rows with columns using for loop in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, rows

[image: Multiply]

i want to  multiply chem volume1 5 value with stage time value 6 then chemvolume 
2 value with 6 of stage time.
then i want to multiply chem volume value 7 with stage time value 8 and then chemvolume2 value 8 with stage time value 8.

using for loop .
5,6,7,8 values of cheme volumes are stored in array while stage time values are stored in other array .

```
for (var i = 0; i < r.length; i++) {

  x= parseFloat(x) +  parseFloat(r[i]);
  x=x.toFixed(4);
  //for water_total
  document.getElementById('water_total').innerHTML=x;
}

var inputs = $(".volo");
var id=0;
for (var j = 0; j < inputs.length;j++) {

  inputss.push($(inputs[j]).val());

  for(var i = j; i < r.length; i++){
    var gh=parseFloat(r[j]) *  parseFloat($(inputs[i]).val());
    alert(parseFloat($(inputs[i]).val()));
    alert(parseFloat(r[j]));
    gh=gh.toFixed(4);

    $('input[id="rates' + id +'"]').val(gh);
    id++;
    document.getElementByClass('rates'+i+'').innerHTML=x;
  }
}
```

Comment: You should add your HTML/arrays to the question too.

Comment: What happens when you run this code?  Note that document.getElementByClass will throw an error as that method doesn't exist ([getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) possibly you meant)